# Qt Creator Linux Breakpoints skipped in plain C++ project

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

Well, the title pretty much says it all.  I start up Qt Creator, I create a new project and click the plain C++ option.  It creates the following code in the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the line beginning with `cout` or `return`.

I set the project mode to debug.

I click the play button with the bug on it.

It doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

If I do the exact same thing but having created a Qt GUI Application, it works.

Help'd be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Oh yeah, if it makes any difference, I'm using the latest version of Linux Mint and from what I can tell, GCC and GDB are installed.

Edit:  Here is the:

Compile Output:

```
23:27:37: Running build steps for project untitled2...
23:27:37: Starting: "/usr/bin/qmake-qt4" '/home/jean-luc/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled2/untitled2.pro' -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug
23:27:37: The process "/usr/bin/qmake-qt4" exited normally.
23:27:37: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/jean-luc/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled2-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../untitled2 -I../untitled2 -I. -o main.o ../untitled2/main.cpp
g++  -o untitled2 main.o      
{ test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'untitled2' && test -f untitled2.gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=untitled2.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'untitled2' 'untitled2' && rm -f untitled2.gdb-index || true
make: Leaving directory `/home/jean-luc/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled2-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Debug'
23:27:38: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
```

Application Output:

> > Debugging starts
> >     Debugging has finished

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu x64, breakpoints work fine with this code...

Comment: Does it print out "Hello World!"?

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you run program in realase mode instead of debug?

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't.  Above the green triangle on the left, I selected debug.  I'm assuming that's all that I need to do.

Comment: @user968243 If you are going to post compile output, can you please post the rebuild output? What you have there is `make` telling you nothing has changed - it's useless.

Comment: Note that after you built in release mode, then change to debug mode, it will not rebuild the project in debug mode (as long as you use the same build directory for both release and debug version). Is the `-g` flag ("debug symbols") present when `g++` is called?

Comment: Sorry about that, pretty stupid of me.  I've chucked the rebuild output up.  Looks to me as though the `-g` flag is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is already a few days old, I'd like to add this resolution, as the problem described occasionally happens with Qt and Creator: Qt Creator has the nasty habit to suggest having the release and the debug objects in the same folder. So if you compile a release build, then decide to debug your program and make a debug build, it will link a debug application with release objects.
These objects cannot have a breakpoint set into. You need to clean the project completely, call qmake and make all in debug mode. Then you should be able to set breakpoints properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give cmake command **cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug**

or

**SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)** add this line to CMakeLists.txt and debug now. Breakpoints will get hit properly.